# Creating relationship Neo4J during import if value is 1

Tags: database, import, neo4j, cypher

Hello all you helpful folks!

I have been tasked with converting our RDBM into a Graph database for testing purposes. I am using Neo4J and have been successful on importing various tables into their appropriate nodes. However, I have run into a slight hiccup when it comes to the department node. Certain department are partnered with a particular department. Within the RDBMS model, this is simple a column named: Is_Partner because this database was originally set up with one partner in mind (Hence the whole: Moving to a Graph database thing).

What I need to do is match all department with the Is_Partner value of 1 and assign a relationship to from the partner who has the value of 1 in Is_Partner and assign it to a specific partner (Edge: ABBR, Value: HR).  I have written the script, but it tells me it's successful, but 0 edits are made...

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Department.csv" AS row
MATCH (partner:Department {DepartmentID: row.DepartmentID})
WHERE row.IS_PARTNER = "1"
MERGE (partner)-[:IS_PARTNER_OF]->(Department{ABBR: 'HR'});
```

I'm pretty new to Graph Databases, but I know Relational Databases quite well. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Jim Perry

Comment: This is right? `MATCH (partner:Department {DepartmentID: row.DepartmentID})`. Why are you assign a `:Department`to a variable called partner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your query. If you want to filter on CSV use `WITH` statement with a `WHERE` filter. Also you want to `MERGE` HR department node separately and then `MERGE` relationship separately.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Department.csv" AS row
WITH row  WHERE row.IS_PARTNER = "1"
MATCH (partner:Department {DepartmentID: row.DepartmentID})
MERGE (dept:Department{ABBR: 'HR'}))
MERGE (partner)-[:IS_PARTNER_OF]->(dept);
```

If it still return `no results/changes`, check out if your `MATCH` statement return anything as this is usually the problem.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Department.csv" AS row
WITH row  WHERE row.IS_PARTNER = "1"
MATCH (partner:Department {DepartmentID: row.DepartmentID})
RETURN partner
```